# Passing values to HTML File STORED in Asset Folder in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I was trying to pass the parameters to HTML file stored in android `Asset Folder`. I was passing the  parameters to the function written in java script on my HTML file. But at certain times, I'm getting `Exception`, which I find difficult to sort out the issue.

Exception::

```
`I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list", source: file:///android_asset/templateOffer.html (1)`.
```

Java script Code in HTML file:

```
 function setWineDetails(tempOffer,wineBrnd,wineName,
         wineCurrency,winePrice,placeLineOne,PlaceLineTwo,userName,wineMtchVal){
                 document.getElementById("usrname").innerHTML = userName;
    document.getElementById("wineTpe").innerHTML = tempOffer;
    document.getElementById("wine_brnd_id").innerHTML = wineBrnd;
    document.getElementById("wine_name_id").innerHTML = wineName;
    document.getElementById("wine_currcy_id").innerHTML = wineCurrency;
    document.getElementById("wine_price_id").innerHTML = winePrice;

    if (placeLineOne != = "" || placeLineOne != = null) {
        document.getElementById("place_line_one_id").innerHTML = placeLineOne;
        document.getElementById("place_line_second_id").innerHTML = PlaceLineTwo;
    }
    if (wineMtchVal == "" || wineMtchVal == null) {
        document.getElementById("wine-percentages").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wine-percentages").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("wineMtch_id").innerHTML = wineMtchVal;
    }
                
        }   
        
        function setImage(wineImage){
                       
            document.getElementById("wineImage_id").src               = wineImage;      
        }
    
        function setValuesToOfferView(offerPercentage,offerExpiry){
            
                  document.getElementById("offer_per_id").innerHTML       = offerPercentage;
                  document.getElementById("offer_expiry_id").innerHTML    = offerExpiry;

        }
```

`passing parameteres::`

```
    private  void loadWebViewContent(){

        offerWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        offerWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                //Here you want to use .loadUrl again
                //on the webview object and pass in
                //"javascript:<your javaScript function"
                offerWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setWineDetails('"+offerTemp+"','"+wineBrand+"','"+wineName+"','"+wineCurrency+"','"+winePrice+"','"+placeLineOne+"','"+PlaceLineTwo+"','"+userName+"','"+wineMatch+"')");
                offerWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setValuesToOfferView('"+offerPercentage+"','"+offerExpiry+"')"); //if passing in an object. Mapping may need to take place
            

offerWebView.loadUrl("javascript:setImage('"+wineImage+"')"); //if passing in an object. Mapping may need to take place
        }
    });
    offerWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/templateOffer.html");
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show how you pass parameters. And which ones.

Comment: @blackapps - sorry for that.. I have Updated it above with the code for passing parameters also.

Comment: `document.getElementById("usrname").innerHTML = userName;` So you had a loadUrl() before which loaded a page as that document.

Comment: @blackapps - so what is the work around for it? could you help me on it?

Comment: You did not answer my last comment. I suggested that you at least called loadUrl() five times. You posted four calls only. Can you please format your code as its hardly to see that three loadUrls are in the same block. Confusing. I think i now understand that first the .html is loaded and in on page finished the java script where you try to put some values.

Comment: Quote: The “missing ) after argument list” message tells us that there is a syntax error inside a function call. This may happen if you add a comma at the end of a list of arguments that is not followed by another argument.

Comment: So are you passing an empty variable?

Comment: @blackapps - some of  the Paramters will be empty . But I was handling that inside the html file by Null checking the value.is that ok?

Comment: Well read the quoted message and decide for yourself. ( I dont think so as your check does not prevent an empty parameter).

Comment: `offerWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:setWineDetails('"+offerTemp+"','"+wineBrand+"','"+wineName+"','"+wineCurrency+"','"+winePrice+"','"+placeLineOne+"','"+PlaceLineTwo+"','"+userName+"','"+wineMatch+"')");` Those parameters should not be empty. Or the last one not. I dont know. Check for emptyness before use. You can always give them a fake value. Upon which you check. But.... I have no idea if this is indeed your problem...
  You did not tell which statement causes the problem.

Comment: @blackapps- some of the parameters are empty, and it may vary upon the use case. I was handling the `emptyness` in the `HTML` file, because the view on the `HTML` should be set to `hidden` and `visible` depending on the value from the parameter